# Geometric meaning of cusps/component labels in Katz-Mazur book

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, moduli-spaces, curves-and-surfaces, modular-curves

In Katz-Mazur book "Arithmetic moduli of elliptic curves" there is a short section (see image below) regarding the cusp-labels and component-labels.

The set of cusps labels intuitively should parametrize the cusps of modular curves. In the last sentence of the section the authors say that thee natural map from cusps to components has some geometric interpretation in the model over $\mathbb Z$ of the curve. I wasn't able to find anywhere in the book the aforementioned geiometric picture. Do you have any suggestion, or can you point out an alternative reference where I can find this piece of information?

**Edit:** As mentionend in a comment, this map should be related to the map that sends a cusp to the irreducible component of the special fibre that contains its reduction modulo $p$. Although I would like to understand how this map explicitly works. For instance how can I find the images of the cusps $0$ and $\infty$?

Moreover, what is the role of $p$? For all primes of good reduction the aforementioned map is constant, so I guess that the only meaningful primes are the bad reduction ones, but I cannot see them in the formulas. In other words I don't see how the second space parametrizes the irreducible components over $p$?

Many thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there any more to this than "sending a cusp of the modular curve to the irreducible component of the special fibre that it lies on"?

Comment: Ok, this is really nice. But how does this map work? For instance take the two  cusps $0,\infty$; in which components $(a,b)$ of the special fibre are they mapped? Is it something computable?